# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when adding inside of php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have upated the question now. Below is the code which i stored in the external js file.

```
$js ='

var i=1;
var siteUrl = "http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'";

$jd = jQuery.noConflict();
function dialog(urlvalue){
    $jd( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    alert("+urlvalue+");
}
$jd(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $jd(".product");

    id.each(function(index,element){
        //var productUrl = $jd(".product").attr("href");
        var productUrl = $jd("a:first-child ", this).attr("href");
        if(productUrl != undefined){
             //console.log(productUrl);
             productUrl = siteUrl + productUrl ; 
             //$jd(this).addClass("item-" + i);
             //console.log("checking"+index);
             $jd(".vm-product-media-container").addClass("view view-first");
             //console.log($jd(".js-recalculate input[name=pid]").val());
             $jd(".view-first", this).append("<button onclick=\"dialog("+productUrl+")\" class=sdlc_quick> Quick View</button>");       
             //console.log(productUrl);
         }
    });
})';
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

I am getting an error missing argument when i clicked on the button quick view. Below is the  code:-

```
$jd(".view-first", this).append("<button onclick=\"dialog("'+productUrl+'")\" class=sdlc_quick> Quick View</button>");
```

Comment: Remove the quotes in the alert .

Comment: It is still showing the error

Comment: I can’t find any errors with JSHint as well. Maybe the error is at some other location. Do you have more JavaScript code in your PHP?

Comment: Apart from this script i have added only external js $doc->addScript('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js');

Comment: Well I think you should proably do something like this `$jd(document).ready(function($jd){`  but to be honest I try to avoid no conflict mode, nothing good ever came to me when using that.

Comment: You don't wrap your variable between quotes when you are calling the dialog() function.

Comment: @Debflav is right: the result of `("<button onclick=\"dialog("+productUrl+")\" class=sdlc_quick> Quick View</button>")` is `"<button onclick=\"dialog(http://sdfsdf.com/)\" class=sdlc_quick> Quick View</button>"`. `dialog(http://sdfsdf.com/)` causes the error. I thought the error was caused at “compile time”.

Comment: I edited the question please check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

http://jsfiddle.net/7uyhr0vh/1/ (tried to understand the html structure, hope i got it right)

I mainly played with quotes and added a click event listener to the 'sdlc_quick' class

```
var i=1;
var siteUrl = "http://google.com";

$jd = jQuery.noConflict();

$jd(document).ready(function(){

    function dialog(urlvalue){
        $jd( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        alert(urlvalue);
    }

    var id = $jd(".product");
    id.each(function(index,element){
        var productUrl = $jd("a:first-child ", element).attr("href");
        if(productUrl != undefined){
            productUrl = siteUrl + productUrl ; 
            var x = $jd(".vm-product-media-container");
            x.addClass("view view-first");
            console.log(x)
            $jd(".view-first").append("<button class=\"sdlc_quick\"> Quick View</button>");
            $jd(".sdlc_quick",this).click(function(){
                dialog(productUrl);
            });
         }
    });
})
```

Comment: Well your answer was correct. i added it on my code and it was working correctly except one thing i am getting all the url in the alert. so i only modified one line:-$jd(".sdlc_quick",this).click(function() and it works fine

Comment: Updated my answer to include your observation. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. now i able to understand and solved my issue